# Migrar wordpress a un directorio

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Estoy intentando colocar una instalación de wordpress a una carpeta, en vez de tenerlo en la raiz del dominio. 
Hago la migración sin problema de midominio.com a midominio.com/carpeta
El problema lo tengo al apuntar el dominio a la carpeta para que el usuario acceda desde midominio.com, el front no tiene problema, pero al acceder al backoffice meto usuario y contraseña, al enviar, refresaca y limpia el formulario sin dar mensaje de error ni nada parecido.

El proceso ha sido:
Migrar la instalacion a una carpeta y comprobar que todo funcionaba ok.
Colocar un archivo .htaccess en la raiz con el siguiente codigo

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?midominio.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/carpeta/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /carpeta/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?midominio.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$carpeta/index.php [L]
```

De manera que en la raiz tengo el .htaccess y la carpeta con la instalación de wordpress.

Desconozco si debo hacer mas configuraciones y/o donde

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con ese código para el .htaccess da un error 403.

Ahora mismo lo tengo con el archivo en la raiz que tenia y en la base de datos la tabla $prefix . "_options", los registros "home" y "siteurl" tengo la ruta real tipo

http://midominio.com/carpeta

tengo acceso al backoffice sin problema.

En principio así funciona ok, por si a alguien le viene bien esta solución.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba el siguiente codigo para el htaccess, reemplaza carpeta por el nombre del directorio que le pusiste.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /carpeta/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /carpeta/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Además de eso, hay que modificar en la base de datos dos registros de la tabla $prefix . "_options", site_url y home